# Why is my isc-dhcp-server not handing out the router address to clients with reserved addresses?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm running `isc-dhcp-server` on Ubuntu 18.04. Clients without a DHCP reservation are able to get an IP address, subnet mask, default gateway and DNS servers from the pool no problem.

As soon as I define a reservation, the client will correctly get the reserved IP address, subnet mask and DNS servers, however the default gateway will be missing, as shown in this screenshot.

[image: TCP/IP settings pane]

Here's my dhcpd.conf file for reference.

```
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;                                             
option domain-name "test.lan";                      
option domain-name-servers 10.127.253.236,10.127.253.237;                    
default-lease-time 86400;                                  
max-lease-time 86400;                                      
failover peer "dhcp-failover" {                                 
         primary;                                          
         address 10.127.253.236;                                  
         port 647;
         peer address 10.127.253.237;                             
         peer port 647;
         max-response-delay 60;
         max-unacked-updates 10;
         mclt 3600;
         split 128;
         load balance max seconds 3;
}

subnet 10.127.253.224 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
         pool {
                  failover peer "dhcp-failover";
                  option routers      10.127.253.225;
                  option subnet-mask  255.255.255.240;
                  range 10.127.253.226   10.127.253.238;
         }
         ignore client-updates;
}

##############################
## START OF IP RESERVATIONS ##
##############################

host MacBook-pro {
  hardware ethernet f0:18:98:35:29:6c;
  fixed-address 10.127.253.227;
}
```